# UIButton on custom Table Cell goes clear background when Cell is pressed

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, swift2, uicolor

I have a  `UIButton` with a background color and white border on a custom `TableViewCell`. When I press the button itself, everything works as expected. But when I press the Cell, the Cell gets slightly grayer on the press and while this happens, the `UIButton`'s background goes to clear/transparent (the white border remains however). How could I keep the button green the entire time? I set it's background color both programmatically via `myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 56/255, green: 191/255, blue: 38/255, alpha: 1.0)` and via the background field in the storyboard Attribute Inspector. How can I get the background to stay the same color the entire time (while the Cell is selected and slightly grayed)?

Comment: what did you do to solve this?

Comment: wow is this still an issue with the current iOS? I unfortunately don't have a clue at this point how I fixed it.I might have followed miOS's answer/comment

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the table cell selection by adding the following line in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** which might solve your issue

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
```

Comment: While this does work for making the button background not disappear upon press, it does completely stop the center cell from being "greyed" when pressed. Ideally I'd like to keep the cell getting "greyed" on contact, but just having the button background stay green instead of disappearing

Comment: @TommyK Instead of setting the selection style set cell's selected view background which will solve your issue.
    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()